# Emulate touch scroll in Java

Tags: java, touch, javafx, desktop-application

I am searching for a way to create a touch application in Java (NOT for mobile devices) with a touch scroll support.
Ive been searching so far and I am investigating how this could be done - what ive found is the MT4J (http://www.mt4j.org/) but it seems that it would not support that (please correct me if i am wrong).
So my question is, how can i emulate a scroll event on a horizontal touch / swipe?

Thanks for help!
Kind Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaFX's touch event framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/gestures.htm).

Here is some sample code from the linked tutorial on handling scroll events:

```
rect.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            if (!event.isInertia()) {
                rect.setTranslateX(rect.getTranslateX() + event.getDeltaX());
                rect.setTranslateY(rect.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
            }
            log("Rectangle: Scroll event" +
                ", inertia: " + event.isInertia() + 
                ", direct: " + event.isDirect());
            event.consume();
        }
});

rect.setOnScrollStarted(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            inc(rect);
            log("Rectangle: Scroll started event");
            event.consume();
        }
});

rect.setOnScrollFinished(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            dec(rect);
            log("Rectangle: Scroll finished event");
            event.consume();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This implements a touch and drag scroller by sub-classing JScrollPane.

Because touch and drag is not enough on its own I have added momentum
so that it 'throws' the scroll when the mouse button is released.

There is no 'bounce' at the ends of the scroll as I cannot afford to
fight a lawsuit against the owners of 'bounce'.

It's not completely encapsulated because, although it works fine if
the view is a jlist, there may be components on the view that need
to modify their response if the panel was being dragged at the time.
Also some components, e.g. JRadioButton, JCheckBox, etc, consume
mouse clicks without passing them up to the container, so you will
need to add TouchScroll's MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to them.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TouchScroll extends JScrollPane implements MouseListener,   MouseMotionListener {
private JScrollBar vbar = this.getVerticalScrollBar();

public TouchScroll(Component view){ // 1-arity CONSTRUCTOR
    super(view);
    view.addMouseListener(this);
    view.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
public TouchScroll() {  super();    }   // 0-arity CONSTRUCTOR

public void setViewportView(Component view) {
    super.setViewportView(view);
    view.addMouseListener(this);
    view.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

private static boolean wasdragged = false;  // other MouseListeners may need to know this ...
public boolean wasDragged() {       return wasdragged;  }   // ... this gives them safe access

static int lastY = 0, distY = 0;
double momentum = 0;    // not really physical momentum but it will be used to 'throw' the scroll when the mouse button is released
static boolean lbdown = false;
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    wasdragged = true;      
    distY = 0;
    int currentY = e.getYOnScreen();
    if(lbdown) {
        distY =  lastY - currentY;
        vbar.setValue(distY + vbar.getValue());
        if(Math.abs(distY) > 1)
            momentum = distY + distY;   // magnify and log the momentum for later use
    }
    lastY = currentY;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        lastY = e.getYOnScreen();
        lbdown = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        lbdown = false;
    if(wasdragged)
        wasdragged = false;

    if(Math.abs(momentum) <= 4.0)   // then assume that the mouse wasn't moving (much) when the button was released
        return;
    // otherwise 'throw' the scroll
    int max = vbar.getMaximum();
    int count;
    double brakingforce = 1.04;     // set an initial braking force
    for(count = 1000; count > 0; count--){  // don't allow it to accidentally go on forever
        momentum = momentum / brakingforce; // apply the brake
        if(Math.abs(momentum) < 1.5)
            brakingforce = 1.02;    // ease off the brake towards the end (gives a slight overrun ala iOS)
        if(Math.abs(momentum) < 1.0)    // bring it to a halt
            break;
        int val = vbar.getValue();
        if(val < 0 || val > max)    // prevent overrun
            break;
        vbar.setValue((int) momentum + val);    // increment the scroll bar
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);       // slow the loop down so the user can see the scroll
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
```

}

Here is a 'bare bones' example of how you might apply it:

```
panel = new JPanel();
jlist = new JList(list);
scroller = new TouchScroll(jlist);
panel.add(scroller);
```

Any components that respond to a mouse release may need to do something like this:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
    if(scroller.wasDragged())
        return;
    actionENTER();
}
```

Lastly, as mentioned earlier, components that consume mouse events will need
to inform the scroller like this:

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(text);
checkbox.addMouseMotionListener(scroller);
checkbox.addMouseListener(scroller);
```